# SATA 3.0 - PC uses lesser speed

Tags: linux, hard-drive, arch-linux, sata, storage

I'm running Arch Linux (Kernel: 6.2.13-arch1-1) on my home server and I have a few hard drives connected.

This is an image of my chipset for reference:
https://www.pronotebook.cz/fotky48726/fotos/_vyr_828_20200306_123224.jpg

I checked and all of them are major SATA 3.0, so I should be getting 6.0GB/s in terms of transfer speed. Surprisingly one of the drives runs on 3.0GB/s and I would like to know why?

Here is some information on the drive in question:

```
➜  sudo smartctl -a /dev/sdb | grep SATA
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.1, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 3.0 Gb/s)
```

```
➜  hdparm -I /dev/sdb

/dev/sdb:

ATA device, with non-removable media
        Model Number:       ST1000DM003-1CH162
        Serial Number:      Z1D9LJ42
        Firmware Revision:  CC49
        Transport:          Serial, SATA 1.0a, SATA II Extensions, SATA Rev 2.5, SATA Rev 2.6, SATA Rev 3.0
Standards:
        Used: unknown (minor revision code 0x001f)
        Supported: 9 8 7 6 5
        Likely used: 9
Configuration:
        Logical         max     current
        cylinders       16383   16383
        heads           16      16
        sectors/track   63      63
        --
        CHS current addressable sectors:    16514064
        LBA    user addressable sectors:   268435455
        LBA48  user addressable sectors:  1953525168
        Logical  Sector size:                   512 bytes
        Physical Sector size:                  4096 bytes
        Logical Sector-0 offset:                  0 bytes
        device size with M = 1024*1024:      953869 MBytes
        device size with M = 1000*1000:     1000204 MBytes (1000 GB)
        cache/buffer size  = unknown
        Form Factor: 3.5 inch
        Nominal Media Rotation Rate: 7200
Capabilities:
        LBA, IORDY(can be disabled)
        Queue depth: 32
        Standby timer values: spec'd by Standard, no device specific minimum
        R/W multiple sector transfer: Max = 16  Current = 16
        Advanced power management level: 128
        Recommended acoustic management value: 208, current value: 0
        DMA: mdma0 mdma1 mdma2 udma0 udma1 udma2 udma3 udma4 udma5 *udma6
             Cycle time: min=120ns recommended=120ns
        PIO: pio0 pio1 pio2 pio3 pio4
             Cycle time: no flow control=120ns  IORDY flow control=120ns
Commands/features:
        Enabled Supported:
           *    SMART feature set
                Security Mode feature set
           *    Power Management feature set
           *    Write cache
           *    Look-ahead
           *    Host Protected Area feature set
           *    WRITE_BUFFER command
           *    READ_BUFFER command
           *    DOWNLOAD_MICROCODE
           *    Advanced Power Management feature set
                Power-Up In Standby feature set
           *    SET_FEATURES required to spinup after power up
                SET_MAX security extension
           *    48-bit Address feature set
           *    Device Configuration Overlay feature set
           *    Mandatory FLUSH_CACHE
           *    FLUSH_CACHE_EXT
           *    SMART error logging
           *    SMART self-test
           *    General Purpose Logging feature set
           *    WRITE_{DMA|MULTIPLE}_FUA_EXT
           *    64-bit World wide name
                Write-Read-Verify feature set
           *    WRITE_UNCORRECTABLE_EXT command
           *    {READ,WRITE}_DMA_EXT_GPL commands
           *    Segmented DOWNLOAD_MICROCODE
           *    Gen1 signaling speed (1.5Gb/s)
           *    Gen2 signaling speed (3.0Gb/s)
           *    Gen3 signaling speed (6.0Gb/s)
           *    Native Command Queueing (NCQ)
           *    Phy event counters
           *    READ_LOG_DMA_EXT equivalent to READ_LOG_EXT
           *    DMA Setup Auto-Activate optimization
           *    Device-initiated interface power management
           *    Software settings preservation
           *    SMART Command Transport (SCT) feature set
           *    SCT Write Same (AC2)
                unknown 206[7]
                unknown 206[12] (vendor specific)
                unknown 206[13] (vendor specific)
Security:
        Master password revision code = 65534
                supported
        not     enabled
        not     locked
                frozen
        not     expired: security count
                supported: enhanced erase
        104min for SECURITY ERASE UNIT. 104min for ENHANCED SECURITY ERASE UNIT.
Logical Unit WWN Device Identifier: 5000c500660d578c
        NAA             : 5
        IEEE OUI        : 000c50
        Unique ID       : 0660d578c
Checksum: correct
```

Looking forward to all of your educational responses :)

Kind regards,

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145788/discussion-on-question-by-trickyzerg-sata-3-0-pc-uses-lesser-speed); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is your assuming your going to get 6gbps per second.

```
SATA 3 can do 600mb/s
SATA 2 can do 300mb/s
SATA 1 can do 150mb/s
```

According to a google search with results from userbenchmark.com your hard drive actually average speed is 147mb/s.  Yes it can peak at 197mb/s but only for a few seconds.

Even 200mb/s is does not approach the ceiling of SATA 2.  So the manufacturer of the hard drive put a slower controller on the hard drive because they knew there hard drive could never even fully utilize SATA 2.  They probably saves $2 a hard drive * 200,000 hdd or $400,000.

While your other hard drives say they're SATA 3 or 6gbps they won't actually give you that speed.

So don't worry about the speed limit when your not even fully using SATA 2.

If you want those speeds only SSD will fully saturate SATA 3.

Think about your car it has a hard speed limit of something like 100mph or more, but there is no public street you could drive that fast.  There are other cars, people, and etc preventing you from achieving this speeds.

Update:  I see that the hard drive does claim SATA 3 support, and in that case either the cable is bad, the SATA port you plugged it into is limited to SATA 2, or perhaps a BIOS setting has limited it to SATA 2 speeds.  However, given the 300mb/s of SATA 2 your data won't come through any faster.

Comment: While it might indeed not matter, `So the manufacturer of the hard drive put a slower controller` is obviously not the reason / answer to this question, you can clearly see from the output there the drive IS a SATA 3 drive. Even if the controller in the drive is not actually capable of handling 6Gbps I/O (I mean like in terms of computation power whatsoever), it is not why `(current: 3.0 Gb/s)` is shown there. (Besides, it might actually hint that some non-bandwidth feature of SATA 3 cannot be enabled because the drive actually got connected to a SATA 2 port)

Comment: @TomYan Which gives me the partial answer: do not expect from any HDD to keep up the maximum potential of allowed speed at all times, when it comes to the SATA version.

Comment: @Cybernard The controller might say SATA 3, but in the comments they says it is an Intel C210 controller which has only lists 2 ports at SATA 6 Gb/s, implying that the remainder are SATA 3 Gb/s. https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/66416/intel-c216-chipset.html

Comment: @Mokubai It says that it has 6 SATA connectors and this is the chipset:

- https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/64027/intel-q77-express-chipset.html

Comment: @TrickyZerg yet it does not say what SATA version those ports support. A [different Q77 manual](https://www.jetwayusa.com/dl/manual/G03-NMF93-F.pdf) says `Support two SATA III ports and four SATA II ports` hence why ***I mentioned needing your specific motherboard model*** because chances are you have some ports that support SATA 6.0Gb/s (SATA III) and some ports that support SATA 3.0Gb/s (SATA II)

Comment: @Mokubai from the pic (admittedly bad quality) I think the model is e93839 la0601

Comment: @Paul you are more patient looking at blurry images than I am. I found the actual computer manual at http://h10032.www1.hp.com/ctg/Manual/c03347207.pdf which confirms my point that some ports are only SATA 2 and would therefore only support 3.0Gb/s and that those connectors are likely the white ones. It would have been better to have the make and model information to begin with in the question, but hey ho.

Comment: @Mokubai Thanks for the manual, now let me not lose that :)